# Possible to modify named std::string on construction?

Tags: c++, stdstring

Does anyone know why the commented line fails compilation but the uncommented line is okay?

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    // std::string foo("hello").erase(2); // This doesn't compile...
    std::string("hello").erase(2);        // ...but this does.
}
```

Including the commented line causes this error:

```
main.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
main.cpp:5: error: expected ‘,’ or ‘;’ before ‘.’ token
```

Can someone explain what the rules are about modifying anonymous versus named `std::string` objects right where they are constructed?

Comment: A declaration is not an expression, that's why.

Comment: More-or-less the same reason you can't write `void f(int i)(5);`.

Comment: @KerrekSB `std::string foo("hello")` is not a declaration (it's a *type-specifier* and a *declarator*).  The declaration would be those things followed by `;` .

Comment: @M.M: I'm pretty sure if you trace the grammar of the production "*declaration*" you'll find the OP's code match (via *block-declaration* and *simple-declaration*).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is an issue that has to do with the syntax for the language. There's a distinction between a declaration, which is a *statement*, and a creation of a temporary, which is an *expression*. The two are handled quite differently by the language and are subject to different rules.

A declaration is a *statement* in which you give the type of a variable, the name, and some expression that initializes it. So, for example, you could write

```
std::string foo("hello");
```

or

```
std::string foo = "hello";
```

However, you cannot write

```
std::string foo("hello").erase(2);
```

simply because the language says that that syntax isn't allowed there. I mean, *I* get what you're saying, and I think most people probably would as well, but the language says that you're not allowed to do that. You could, however, write

```
std::string foo = std::string("hello").erase(2);
```

because declaration statements do allow you to provide arbitrary expressions as initializers.

On the other hand, the *expression*

```
std::string("hello").erase(2)
```

is perfectly well-formed as an expression, because expressions can be built by creating temporary objects or calling member functions on different objects.

So really, there's no reason why the language *couldn't* have been designed so that what you're doing would be legal, but it just *wasn't* designed that way.

Comment: Also consider: `std::string foo("hello").find('l');` At least for `const` methods, it doesn't even make sense for them to be callable there.

Answer (score 5):

The statement that creates a named local, global, or namespace-scoped variable is called a *definition*. A definition is **not** an expression, and you cannot expect that everything allowed in an expression is also allowed in a definition. A definition is strictly limited to initializing the object it defines.

The second statement is an expression, so there, you can call whatever member functions on the object you wish.